# How to set up two transaction managers?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-batch

I am working on a Spring application that has already set up a transaction manager.

In a configuration class it has already set up an entity manager reading from a persistence.xml and then sets up a JpaTransactionManager.

I am required to create a Spring Batch implementation and the problem is that, as I have found out from different posts, when using the `@EnableBatchProcessing`  annotation it seems that a second transaction manager is registered and I cannot persist data inside my tasklets.

Is it possible to use two transaction managers or configure my application in a way that I will be able to persist my data?

Can you please provide me with sample code?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This is the application config class, which already exists in the application:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({
    ...
})
@EnableJpaRepositories("...")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaAuditing
@Import({SecurityConfig.class})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:/META-INF/persistence.xml");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

this is my batch config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory")
    private LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean batchEntityManagerFactory;


}
```

from which I am getting an:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean com.xxx.xxx.xxx.configuration.BatchConfig.batchEntityManagerFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.sp
ringframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=entityManagerFactory)}
```

EDIT 2:
This is what I have done:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("xxx")
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class BatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Autowired
    private ReportReaderProcessor reportReaderProcessor;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:/META-INF/persistence.xml");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer() {
        return new DefaultBatchConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
                JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
                jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
                return jpaTransactionManager;
            }
        };
    }
    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setTransactionManager(batchConfigurer().getTransactionManager());
        return (JobRepository) factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository());
        return simpleJobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step readReports() {
        return steps
                .get("readReports")
                .tasklet(reportReaderProcessor)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job reportJob() {
        return jobs
                .get("submitReportJob")
                .start(readReports())
                .build();
    }
}
```

but now I am getting an other error:

```
15:47:23,657 ERROR [stderr] (pool-36-thread-1) org.springframework.transaction.InvalidIsolationLevelException: DefaultJpaDialect does not support custom isolation levels due to limitations in standard JPA. Specific arrangements may be implemented in custom JpaDialect variants.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open issue for this case here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2294 which is fixed in version 4.1.0.M3. To use a custom transaction manager, you need to provide a `BatchConfigurer` in your application context, for example:

```
@Bean
public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer() {
    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
           return new MyTransactionManager();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You would still need to provide a `BatchConfigurer` and implement `getTransactionManager` returning the existing transaction manager. Spring Batch won't make the decision of which transaction manager to use. It would be great if you try with version 4.1.0.M3 and give us your feedback! Many thanks upfront.

Comment: is this still the way to get spring batch to use a JpaTransactionManager in 4.1.2? I found myself with the error "Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@32c3d9cf] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)]" when trying to use my jpa respository, but I then found your answer in the following thread https://gitter.im/spring-batch/Lobby?at=5dc40c9b9c39821509fbf48e.and here in this post. I've been successfully able to get things to work with this solution, but wanted to be sure it's the correct way in the current version of spring batch.

Comment: Yes, this did not change since 4.1.0.M3.